# DOS command for creation date file

Tags: command-line-interface, ms-dos

I've been wondering, using this dos command

```
for %a in (MyFile.txt) do set FileDate=%~ta
```

Is there a way to have the full date from the day to the second?

EDIT:

For now I get :

```
set FileDate=04/08/2011 15:37
```

What I want is :

```
set FileDate=04/08/2011 15:37:04
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want/expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The %~tX output uses the short-format as defined in your regional settings.
Unfortunately the short-format can never include seconds (at least on Win7, not sure about other Windows versions).

As far as I know there is no way to do what you want using just cmd-script commands.
You will need an extra utility that pulls the full date/time info from the file-system.

Comment: It works this way in XP as well.

Comment: @RobW: Thanks, I didn't have any XP boxes around to check myself.

Comment: If seconds are important, the data is stored, just not available via the FOR command.  You can look at the GNU utils STAT.EXE command (via this project: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html). STAT.EXE shows that seconds are stored.  With only lite looking, I've not found another way to get to the seconds.

Comment: A port of stat would do the trick indeed.  And bare in mind that FAT file-systems only store the seconds with 2 second resolution.

Answer (score -2):

First: That's not a "DOS command".  *DOS has nothing to do with it and is not involved at all.*  It is the built in `FOR` command of `CMD`, Microsoft's default command interpreter that is bundled with Windows NT.  The `FOR` command in Microsoft's `COMMAND`, its command interpreter for DOS, has no such functionality, not least because DOS has no notion of file creation timestamps.

Second: As a command interpreter built-in this sort of thing depends from what command interpreter one actually uses in the first place.  What you want is dead easy to achieve with [JP Software's command interpreter TCC](http://jpsoft.com./tccle_cmd_replacement.html), for example:

```
[C:\]echo %@filedate[config.sys,c,4] %@filetime[config.sys,c,s]
2008-11-07 18:11:38

[C:\]
```